# Доброго времени суток,мне нужно вывести список студентов из арайлиста.Проблема в том,что при выводе мой код выводит (как я понял)ссылку,а не значение

Tags: java, массивы, классы

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       ArrayList<Student> lisNumStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();

        lisNumStudents.add(new Student("Name" , "Lastname" , 5 )) ;



        for(int j = 0 ; j<lisNumStudents.size();j++){
            Student s = lisNumStudents.get(j) ;
            System.out.println(s.toString());

        }
    }
}
class Student {private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private int course;
    private double exammark1 = 1 ;
    private double exammark2 = 1 ;
    private double exammark3 = 1 ;
    private double exammark4 = 1 ;
    private double exammark5 = 1 ;
    private double exammark6 = 1 ;
    private double exammark7 = 1 ;
    private double exammark8 = 1 ;

    public double getAvgMark() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void passExam(int mark){

    }

    public Student(String name, String lastName, int course ) {
        this.name = name ;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.course = course;

    }
    public Student(String name, String lastName, int course , int exammark1 ,int exammark2 ,int exammark3 ,int exammark4 ,int exammark5 , int exammark6 , int exammark7 , int exammark8 ) {
        this.name = name ;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.course = course;
        this.exammark1 = exammark1 ;
        this.exammark2 = exammark2 ;
        this.exammark3 = exammark3 ;
        this.exammark4 = exammark4 ;
        this.exammark5 = exammark5 ;
        this.exammark6 = exammark6 ;
        this.exammark7 = exammark7 ;
        this.exammark8 = exammark8 ;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getCourse() {
        return course;

    }

    public double getExammark1() {
        return exammark1;

    }
    public double getExammark2() {
        return exammark2;

    }
    public double getExammark3() {
        return exammark3;

    }
    public double getExammark4() {
        return exammark4;

    }
    public double getExammark5() {
        return exammark5;

    }
    public double getExammark6() {
        return exammark6;

    }
    public double getExammark7() {
        return exammark7;

    }
    public double getExammark8() {
        return exammark8;

    }

    public String setName(String name) {
        if (name != null && name != "") {
            this.name = name.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + name.substring(1);
        }
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setLastName(String name1) {
        if (name1 != null && name1 != "") {
            lastName = name1.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + name1.substring(1);
        }
    }

    public void setCourse(int course1) {
        if (course1 > 0 && course1 <= 120) {
            course = course1;
        }
    }
    public void setExamMark1(double exammark1) {
        if (exammark1 > 0 && exammark1 <= 5) {
            this.exammark1 = exammark1;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Слишком много баллов");
        }

    }
    public void setExamMark2(double exammark2) {
        if (exammark2 > 0 && exammark2 <= 5) {
            this.exammark2 = exammark2;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Слишком много баллов");
        }

    }
    public void setExamMark3(double exammark3) {
        if (exammark3 > 0 && exammark3 <= 5) {
            this.exammark3 = exammark3;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Слишком много баллов");
        }

    }
    public void setExamMark4(double exammark4) {
        if (exammark4 > 0 && exammark4 <= 5) {
            this.exammark4 = exammark4;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Слишком много баллов");
        }

    }
    public void setExamMark5(double exammark5) {
        if (exammark5 > 0 && exammark5 <= 5) {
            this.exammark5 = exammark5;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Слишком много баллов");
        }

    }
    public void setExamMark6(double exammark6) {
        if (exammark6 > 0 && exammark6 <= 5) {
            this.exammark6 = exammark6;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Слишком много баллов");
        }

    }
    public void setExamMark7(double exammark7) {
        if (exammark7 > 0 && exammark7 <= 5) {
            this.exammark7 = exammark7;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Слишком много баллов");
        }

    }
    public void setExamMark8(double exammark8) {
        if (exammark8 > 0 && exammark8 <= 5) {
            this.exammark8 = exammark8;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Слишком много баллов");
        }


    }

    public double getAvgMArk1(){
        return (getExammark1() + getExammark2() + getExammark3() + getExammark4() + getExammark5() + getExammark6() + getExammark7() + getExammark8())/8 ;
    }}
```

Comment: вывод :com.company.Student@378bf509

Comment: переопределите метод toString в объекте Student или выводите s.getName() + " " + s.getLastName()

Comment: спасибо , помогло